# How to make a list of all errors appear in a JFrame

Tags: java

I have made an application which allows users to check their sales and buying history on a fake simulation of an ebay type interface. When they try to enter a negative amount or try to but something they don't have enough money for an error message appears as a JOptionPane

is there a way to display all the errors that occured on a JFrame at the end for an administrator or someone similar to view?

Comment: Why don't you use a table?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of presenting an error with a JOptionPane, either log the error (look into slf4j for a slick logging interface) or create an object that represents the error and handle it by whatever means you prefer.